# How to access object data using variable value as element in vue js

Tags: javascript, html

How i can access the object data using variable value as key?

Let say i have this object:

```
let item = {
    name: {
        first_name: "Mark",
        last_name: "James"
    }
}
```

How i can get the value of first name using variable value? 
I know i can access it using

> item.name.first_name

What if i want to access it using variable value like this:

```
let key = "name.first_name"

console.log(item[key])
```

Comment: @StevenB. it seems you don't understand my question. I want to store my key inside the variable like this key = "name.first_name"

Comment: You can see code here: https://replit.com/@BugsFounder/objectKeyParser#index.js